# Are $g_1$ and $g_2$ elements of $\langle g_1g_2\rangle$ when $g_1$ and $g_2$ commute and have co-prime orders?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Consider a finite group $G$. Let $g_1$ and $g_2$ two elements of $G$ that commute and have co-prime orders. Are $g_1$ and $g_2$ elements of $\langle g_1g_2\rangle$ ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Please, read carefully the question before closing it. The OP asks "is it possible to generate $g_1$ and $g_2$ from $g_1g_2$?", I don't see how it relates to the problem you link.

Comment: @Crostul Sorry, I read that $g_1g_2$ [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135717/cyclic-group-g-with-generator-ab?noredirect=1&lq=1) generates the whole group $G$, hence also $g_1$ and $g_2$. The assumption was, however, that $G$ is abelian. So the question is reopened.

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you think this might be true? Do you know any structural theorems for finite abelian groups?

Comment: BTW this was a cross-post (1 hour later) from MO (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353909/) where it's been closed and deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $o(g_1)=m$ and $o(g_2)=n$, so gcd$(m,n)=1$. By Bézout's Theorem we can find $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $1=km+ln$. It follows that $g_1=g_1^{ln}$ and $g_2=g_2^{km}$. Hence $(g_1g_2)^{ln}=g_1$ and $(g_1g_2)^{km}=g_2$.

Comment: @RTK If you deem this answer the right one,please tick it as such, complying with the StackExchange rules, thanks.